# Fibre provider - new account holder

Tags: united-kingdom

I am in England, UK.

As the account holder, I got into a contract with a residential fibre optic provider for X per month and I am due for renewal. I pay out of my account through direct debit. The company quoted me for the exact same service a price of X+20 per month to stay as an existing customer.

New customers pay X-10. My wife lives with me. Can she become a new customer / new account holder and pay X-10 per month instead of me remaining as the account holder and paying X+20?

Is what I want to do illegal? Besides immoral, is it legal for the company to charge existing customers more?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's legal for the company to charge existing customers more. The general practice was actually [recently made illegal](https://www.fca.org.uk/publications/policy-statements/ps21-11-general-insurance-pricing-practices-amendments) for parts of the insurance market but that's a very specific case in a more highly regulated industry.

But it seems a pretty well established part of the UK internet/mobile phone industry now that companies will raise their headline rates ridiculously high but be very willing to bargain.

So before you try the "switch account to my wife" option, I'd suggest just telling them you're planning on leaving and see how low they go.

Answer (score 1):

It is not immoral for a company to charge existing customers more.  We may not like it and decry it as poor business practices but this is common across many industries.  Here in the US, one can get paid a decent amount for just opening a checking account.

Unless you lie about something it is likely not illegal for your wife to apply to be a new account holder.  Once you lie, it falls into the category of fraud.  Will they prosecute?  Highly unlikely.  However, the company might have a policy from allowing this kind of thing and will likely have safe guards to prevent it.

Bills suck, it is part of being an adult.  In my own case, my internet provider guaranteed to not raise rates.  However, to collect more money they reduced the discount one receives for automatic payment.  The end result being my costs went up.